# Django Models disappear from app deployed in Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am building a personal portfolio website with Django which I'm hoping to host on Heroku. I am aware of the platform's ephemeral storage problem so all of the images are served from an s3 bucket. After deploying the app though and running the `python manage.py migrate` from the dyno and check the `postgresql` database on the dashboard I can see rows and columns created but they're not populated. Therefore, there are no models stored in this database. I'm not `.gitignore`-ing the `db.sqlite3`. I'm also using a virtual environment.
Ih short here's the output of the `tree` command from the root folder:

```
├── Procfile
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── media
│   └── images
│       ├── angular.png
│       ├── bash.png
│       ├── c.png
│       ├── calibration.png
│       ├── commerce_img.png
│       ├── css3.png
│       ├── django.png
│       ├── git.png
│       ├── html.png
│       ├── image-processing-api.png
│       ├── js-logo.png
│       ├── mail.png
│       ├── my_store.png
│       ├── network.png
│       ├── nodejs.png
│       ├── programmer.svg
│       ├── python.png
│       ├── rest_with_node.png
│       ├── sql.png
│       ├── typescript.png
│       └── wiki_image.png
├── portfolio
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-39.pyc
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── requirements.txt
├── staticfiles
└── webdev_portfolio
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
    │   ├── admin.cpython-39.pyc
    │   ├── apps.cpython-39.pyc
    │   ├── models.cpython-39.pyc
    │   ├── tech_stack.cpython-39.pyc
    │   ├── urls.cpython-39.pyc
    │   └── views.cpython-39.pyc
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── static
    │   └── webdev_portfolio
    │       └── styles.css
    ├── templates
    │   └── webdev_portfolio
    │       ├── index.html
    │       ├── layout.html
    │       ├── project.html
    │       └── projects.html
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

Finally here's my `settings.py` file in case I missed something:

```
...
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
       'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

Am I missing something?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So you are using psql on Heroku trying to populate it with `db.sqlite3` file? If that is your intention that is not going to work. Both databases are different, in fact, to populate a newly created PSQL you would need either a fixture or backup.

Check the [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups#direct-database-to-database-copies)